# How do I know whether there is a specific listener on an element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, events

Or how do I know whether this below has been run or not:

```
$target.bind('click',function() {
...
});
```

Comment: Do you mean for debugging purposes or at runtime?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I use the [visual event bookmarklet](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) to show me which items have events.

Comment: There's also firequery, a plugin for firebug, but it takes up memory so I disabled it. http://firequery.binaryage.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `jQuery.data` object to find out:

```
$.fn.isBound = function() {
    return this.length && typeof $.data(this[0], 'handle') == 'function' || false;
}

if ($target.isBound()) {
    // $target has events
}
```

UPDATE: if you want to check for specific types you can look in the `events` object:

```
$.fn.isBound = function(type) {
    return this.length && $.data(this[0], 'events')[type] || false;
}

if ($target.isBound('click')) {
    // $target has clickevents
}
```

Comment: I need to know whether `click` handler is bound

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from and extending David's example, use this:

```
if(typeof $('#id').click == 'function') {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $._data. 
For example

```
$target.bind('click',function() {
...
});

$._data( $target[0], 'events'); // Object {click: Array[1]}
```