# jquery click events being stacked and executed

Tags: jquery, drupal

using the following code (in drupal)

```
    ( function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.auction_house = {
    attach: function(context,settings) {

      $(document).ready(function(){
        // buy item animation
        $(".buy_item_button").click(function() {
          $(".slide_bags").fadeOut(222).fadeIn(222);
          return false;
        });
        // datagrid
        $('#auction_house_table').dataTable();   
      });

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

if I click, the event is fired, if I click another time, the event is fired 2 times, then 3 times, then 4 times and so on. So let's call this 'being stacked'. Important information: the content containing the link were the onclick function is attached to, is loaded through ajax.

How can this happen and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are binding the `'click'` event multiple times (when the ajax content is loaded or so). You can either `unbind` the event before binding it again or check if the event is already bound before re-binding:

Unbind before binding the event:

```
$(".buy_item_button").unbind('click').click(function() {
    //your code...
});
```

Additionally, see **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6361507/112731)** for checking if an event is already bound to an element.

But I think the best approach would be to bind the `click` event only to the latest added content. So, instead of binding the event directly to the `.buy_item_button` selector; you can select the new content and `find` the children with `.buy_item_button` class:

```
$("#new-content").find(".buy_item_button").click(function() {
    //your code...
});
```