# Javascript How to tell if event.preventDefault has occurred on a listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

This should be an easy one :)

I want to add a click event listener only in case it hasn't been added earlier already, and prevent it from running twice. I thought of accomplishing this like so:

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"> Google is your friend </a>
<a href="http://www.Bing.com"> Bing's alright as well </a>
```

**JS**

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
{
    if (*Default has been prevented for links[i]*){ //how do I implement this check?
        return; //do nothing, we're all done.
    } else {
        links[i].addEventListener("click",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Showing you this instead of opening this link!"); 
        });
    }
}
```

In my real world case the added event listener is preventing the default behavior. So how can I check if it has been prevented before? I want to make sure the listener won't be added twice. How can I implement this check? 
Many thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Use event delegation instead.

Comment: Not adding the listener twice can be achieved by not adding the listener twice

Comment: Well, obviously enough, yeah. But this is a rather simplified example of what is happening in my project, so it we'll be readable. I just thought to try and tackle this problem from this angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive your goal using object identity. Quote [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener):

> Multiple identical event listeners
>
> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
>   EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
>   discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and
>   since the duplicates are discarded, they do not need to be removed
>   manually with the removeEventListener method.

Example:

```
// the "one" handler function instance
var theEventPreventDefaultHandler = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener("click", theEventPreventDefaultHandler);
}
```

Watch the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DS6Zg/).

<strike>I didn't check that out, but it could be possible the `addEventListener` function returns false to catch the case, when it didn't add a "duplicate".</strike> It doesn't, returns only `undefined`.

To "check if an event has a handler" is not supported natively. It is possible in jQuery, because this manages the handlers in a `.data("events")` array, also to support IE's old quirks behaviors in `this` and `window.event`. That said, it would be a pain in the ass to reimplement what ejohn did. There about are a bunch of questions on stackoverflow:

- [test if event handler is bound to an element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236067/test-if-event-handler-is-bound-to-an-element-in-jquery)
- [Answer on "How to check if click event is already bound - JQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6361507/1352471)
- ... [google "jquery check bound event"](https://www.google.de/search?q=jquery%20check%20bound%20event)