# How can I check if scroll binding was added to window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to check if scroll event was bound to window element in jQuery. Basically I want to see if someone has done something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { ... });
```

After looking for a little bit on Stack Overflow, I have found more common question like [if event already exist on an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element) with a working solution.

But when I tried to use `$.data( $(window).get(0), 'events' )` I get `undefined`. Similar solution is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery) as well.

So what is the correct way to check for scroll event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
$._data(window).events.scroll
```

That return `undefined` if there is no such event was binded to the `window` object

Example:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/VnLgC/)

```
alert($._data(window).events.scroll); // Should return 'undefined'

$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('a');
});

alert($._data(window).events.scroll); // Should return 1 object

$(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('b');
});

alert($._data(window).events.scroll); // Should return 2 objects
```

Comment: Did not know about $._data. Thank you.