# Get single event on click on div in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var id=100;

for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
 $("#divtext_"+id).click(function(e) {
   onClicked();
 });
}

function onClicked() {
  alert("Clicked")
}
```

- I tried with `.on()` , `delegate()`, and `one()` events.
- When I clicked div, the `onClicked()` function gave an `alert()` 4 times.
- Is it possible when I click div text/image to get one time function/alert?

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<2;i++){`

Comment: You use variable `id` in your loop, that does not change. Did you intend to use `i` in your loop? Currently you set handler for the same component in each iteration, so it fires 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would expect the code to run under jquery, the options here would be to either use .unbind (http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove all previous instructions for this div or to check if the event has already been bound, this has been covered here. [How to check if click event is already bound - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have divs with IDs `divtext_0` ... `divtext_4`

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
 $("#divtext_"+i).click(function(e) {
   onClicked();
 });
}

function onClicked() {
  alert("Clicked")
}
```

At the moment you are adding multiple click handlers to the div `divtext_100` - rather than adding one click handler to multiple divs.

It is hard to say what is best without seeing your HTML - but if you gave all your divs a  class, e.g. 'clickable', then you can avoid any loops and make any div with that class clickable.

```
<div class="clickable"></dvi>
```

You could simply do.

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  onClicked();
});

function onClicked() {
  alert("Clicked")
}
```

Comment: my div id having single id i.e **divtext_100**, actually in my project `$("#divtext_"+id).click(function(e) {
   onClicked();
 });` is in reload function we did not used for loop, example i written for loop instant of reload function. that reload function call click event every 20 seconds.

Comment: if i click after 40 seconds i get two alerts, and wait for 60 seconds then i clicked it s given 3 alerts.

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what you are talking about. If you have code that is causing a problem you should include it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#divtext_"+id).one("click", function(e){
  onClicked();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    $("#divtext_"+id).off('click',onClicked).on('click',onClicked);

```
function onClicked() {
    alert("Clicked")
}
```

'.off' prevents binding of onClicked function multiple times. I think using `.off` will solve your  problem.
If you are using older version of jquery then use `.unbind`.