# Check if event already bound (KEYUP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I've got the following code:

```
$(function(){

    var $name = $('#name'),
        $save = $('#save');

    function alertName(){

        var name = $name.val();

        return alert(name);
    };

    function addSaveEvent(elem){

        return elem.bind('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();alertName();});
    };

    $name.bind('keyup',function(){addSaveEvent($save);});
    $(window).load(function(){
        $save.bind('click',function(e){e.preventDefault();});
    });
});
```

**What is the function?** When the page loads, the button is 'not' clickabled eg. the button does nothing. When the input field "name" changes, the button 'becomes' clickable and will call the function alertName().

**What is the problem?** Everytime something is typed -> everytime a new "keyup", so if you type 'Hello' in the input field 'name' and you click on the button, the function alertName() is fired 5 times (H E L L O). If you delete this and click the button again, it's fired 10 times (H E L L O [backspace]x5).

I think that every time the 'keyup' event is fired, the function addSaveEvent is bind on the save button. But I don't want this, i just want it to be bound only once, not 5, 10, ... times.

**How can I check if an event is already bound to an element? If not => bind, if so => no extra bind (but also NO unbind)?**

Thanks in advance!

PS:
I have checked the following questions:
- [How to check if click event is already bound - JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361465/how-to-check-if-click-event-is-already-bound-jquery)
- [jQuery check if event exists on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515069/jquery-check-if-event-exists-on-element)

Those are about the 'click' event, and not about the 'keyup' event, and I don't understand them very well. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$name.one('keyup',function(){addSaveEvent($save);});
```

[jQuery docs for `one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

In short: binds an event handler that is called and removed the first time it is triggered.