# Partial View Works with JQuery Partially, But Not Completely C# ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is an `ASP.Net MVC 5` Project.

I have a simple `jQuery` to fade in and fade out `HTML` elements on mouse hovering as shown:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
  $('.entrisButton').hover(function ()
    { $(this).fadeTo(1, 1); },
    function ()
    { $(this).fadeTo(1, 0.1); }
  );
</script>
```

Used in the following partial `MyPartialView.cshtml` `View` (the `jQuery` script is in the same `MyPartialView.cshtml` file):

```
<h2>
  @Html.Raw(Model.GetHeaderHtml())  
    <span class="entrisButton">
      <small>
        <span title="Add new entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-success"></span>
        <span title="Change this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-primary"></span>
        <span title="Delete this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger"></span>
      </small>
    </span>
</h2>
```

And here is the effect of the `jQuery`:

[image: Before mouse in]

[image: When mouse hover]

Which is OK... however, the partial `MyPartialView.cshtml` above is called multiple times in another `cshtml` file like this:

```
@if (Model != null) {
  <hr/>
  if (Model.Any()) {
    foreach (var item in Model) { //do something foreach item
      @Html.Partial("MyPartialView", item);
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting in a page rendered like this:

---

[image]

---

As you can see, there are three different results for letter "a" (one `MyPartialView.cshtml` is rendered per result) and each of them have the three glyphicons right beside the query results - faded out.

Now, the first two "a" show expected behavior when the mouse is hover over:

**OK**

---

[image]

---

But the last "a" does not show the expected behavior, the fade-in fade-out does not work though the mouse has hovered over it:

**NOT OK**

---

[image]

---

I notice the problem occurs, whenever the above query result (in this case is the second "a") has the ordered list (as in 1, 2, 3 above), then the below `MyPartialView.cshtml` does not show the desired behavior. As you notice in my example, the first "a" does not have ordered list - so the fade-in and out works. The second "a" **has** an ordered list - the fade-in and out also works. But the third "a" is *after* the query result with an ordered list - it *doesn't* work.

The behavior is consistent when the query result is, let say, only two and the first one has the ordered list, then the fade-in and out in the second one does not show up.

Hence, I suspect the problem with the ordered list, but I cannot figure out why. Here is my `MyPartialView.cshtml`:

```
@using MyProject.Models
@using System.Linq;
@model ResultPerPhrase

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script>
  $('.entrisButton').hover(function ()
    { $(this).fadeTo(1, 1); },
    function ()
    { $(this).fadeTo(1, 0.1); }
  );
</script>

<h2>
  @Html.Raw(Model.GetHeaderHtml())  
    <span class="entrisButton">
      <small>
        <span title="Add new entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-success"></span>
        <span title="Change this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-primary"></span>
        <span title="Delete this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger"></span>
      </small>
    </span>
</h2>

@if (Model.results.Count() > 1) {
  <ol>
    @foreach (var result in Model.results) {
      <li>@Html.Raw(result.ToString())
        <span class="entrisButton">
          <span title="Add new entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-success"></span>
          <span title="Change this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-primary"></span>
          <span title="Delete this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger"></span>
        </span>
      </li>
    }
  </ol>
} else {
  <ul style="list-style: none;" class="adjusted-par">
    @foreach (var result in Model.results) {
      <li>@Html.Raw(result.ToString())
        <span class="entrisButton">
          <small>
            <span title="Add new entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign text-success"></span>
            <span title="Change this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-primary"></span>
            <span title="Delete this entry" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle text-danger"></span>
          </small>
        </span>
      </li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

What could go wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you just need to put your javascript code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ yourCodeHere })` or inside `$(function(){ yourCodeHere })`...both are equivalent .

Comment: You hit the mark! That's it! Thanks a lot, friend! :D But why?

Comment: I am going to post an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why your JavaScript code runs `before` your `Html Dom` was loaded. In order to avoid such behavior you need to enclose your javascript code inside `$(document).ready(f‌​unction(){ yourCodeHere })` or inside `$(function(){ yourCodeHere }`(shorthand version). You can check the documentation here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

So your code needs a minor change:

```
 $(function(){
     $('.entrisButton').hover(function ()
         { $(this).fadeTo(1, 1); },
         function ()
         { $(this).fadeTo(1, 0.1); 
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are placing your hover script in `MyPartialView.cshtml`, it will bind the hover event to the elements multiple times when you call the partial method multiple time if you just wrap the code in `$(function(){...}`.

Check this [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6v7s0dzL/). You can see in console that when the mouse hovers over the div in console two lines are printed because two events are fired.

You should move the hover script outside of the `MyPartialView.cshtml`, or check before binding the hover event. Check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930078/1682148) or check this updated [jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6v7s0dzL/1/)(notice that `here2` is not printed in the console)